# terminate app in background swift

Tags: swift, xcode, appdelegate

I need write some code for my app(in Swift) that should be executed before app termination. It works when I use appWillTerminate in appDelegate when it's not in background but I need it to run the code when it terminates in both background or foreground. How can I do it ??

Comment: What code do you need to execute? If you are just trying to save data, this can be accomplished in other ways.

Comment: the appWillTerminate: it's not called if the app is in the background and there is no way of calling it. I would suggest to write the code in the applicationDidEnterBackground: as after that there is no way of calling the appWillTerminate. But again, it depdens on what are you trying to accomplish. If it's about saving data than applicationDidEnterBackground is the way to go.

Comment: @ahmad have you got any solution, even i have similar case. I want to clear userdefaults when app terminates. It is working fine when app is in foreground mode, but when app is in background mode "appWillTerminate" method is not being called. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The following strategy might work, and it's a more of a pure Swift language approach to take than an iOS one: Every class can override the `deinit` method. Whenever the class needs to be freed from the heap, the [de-initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html) is called before the class is freed. This could happen such as when the class falls out of scope, and has no more retain counts. This will probably happen for your `AppDelegate` when your app is terminating.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in this method `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` in applicationDidEnterBackground. This method give to your application extra time for finishing some task what you need to finish. More documentations is here **Executing Finite-Length Tasks :** https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

If app is in background and don't have any task executing, then the app is in suspend.
When app is in suspend, terminate app will not call applicationWillTerminate. But ,you can start background task
or enable background modes.
e.g.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "MyTask") {
            application.endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask!)
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }

 }
```